# i draw a circle with pygame, but it says i have too many arguments

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a game for a project and am trying to figure out how to draw a circle that I can use as a button. I have used the pygame.draw.circle function. here is my current code:

```
import pygame
block_color = (0, 0, 255)
display_height = 600
display_width = 600
pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, block_color, (50, 50), 20, 0)
thing_width = 100
thing_height = 100
thing_startx = 10
thing_starty = 10
circle(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)
pygame.display.update()
```

according to the pygame function documentation, this should work, but all I get is:

```
line 12, in <module>
circle(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)
NameError: name 'circle' is not defined
```

Comment: You're calling `pygame.draw.rect`.  It takes 4 arguments and draws a rectangle.  You want to call `pygame.draw.circle` to draw a circle.

Comment: Also you're calling a `circle` function that might not exist later on in your code.

Comment: But @TomKarzes is right about the source of *this* error.

Comment: I am sorry I did not relize that but I fixed it and just updated it

Comment: I also realized that I had left a previous line where I left a function that I deleted. Now can anyone help me with making it so that if my sprite goes over it, it will trigger something?

Comment: Do you want a pixel perfect circle button or can it be a rect with roughly the size of the circle? Pixel perfect collision detection is more difficult.

Comment: I would kind of like a perfect circle, but would the pygame.draw.polygon function be easy to detect?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to change the title, maybe to something like "How to implement a button with a circle shape".

Answer (score 3):

You are using [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) instead of [`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle). Try the following instead:

```
pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, block_color, (50, 50), 20, 0)
```

---

> `circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0) -> Rect`
>   Draws a circular shape on the Surface. The pos argument is the center of the circle, and radius is the size. The width argument is the thickness to draw the outer edge. If width is zero then the circle will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance to the center of the circle with the [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function. If the distance is below the radius, the circle was clicked.

```
import math
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    circle_pos = (300, 200)
    circle_radius = 40

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # x and y distance to the mouse position (event.pos).
                x_offset = event.pos[0] - circle_pos[0]
                y_offset = event.pos[1] - circle_pos[1]
                distance = math.hypot(x_offset, y_offset)
                if distance < circle_radius:
                    print('Circle clicked.', distance)


        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.draw.circle(screen, (240, 120, 0), circle_pos, circle_radius)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

You could also use [`pygame.mask.Mask`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html)s for the collision detection, but the `hypot` solution is simpler.

Comment: If you want to use arbitrary polygons, you have to use masks.

Comment: skrx, thank you for the help, but I want to make a button that is activated when my sprite goes on top of it, not when my mouse clicks it.

Comment: You can still use this solution, you just have to check if the distance of the two center points is less than the sum of the radii.

Comment: It would also be possible to use sprites and then check the collisions with `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` and [`pygame.sprite.collide_circle`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) as the callback function.

Comment: How can I detect if my player has gone over something multiple times and how many times?

Comment: You have to increment a `counter` variable, e.g. `if collided: counter += 1`. The problem is that the counter will be incremented every frame, so you have to figure out a mechanism to prevent that.